# Laravel filesystem disk update from ui

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am trying to use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup package to manage backups for my app. I have successfully integrated that and can make a backup to local or s3 disk.

I would like to add the ability for the admin to be able to change the s3 credentials (KEY/secrets) from the admin panel. I am confused here how to get that done? Please guide me how can I change/modify these credentials from the Admin panel. I am a newbie. What I would like is a UI interface to connect S3 bucket to the app and be able to update and link a new S3 account.

the app will use this to store its backups

Comment: It seems a bit unclear to me, but could you not store the API/KEY in the database, and allow the user to modify them with a form?

Comment: I can do it that way but I wanted something like you have a button to get the key using something like link your dropbox button service

Comment: @dmSherazi Did you manage to setup the notifications with mail or slack? I can't seem to figure it out for Laravel 5.3